# Как сохранить значение input в localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Есть задача запомнить путем записи в local storage введенное значение в input с атрибутами `name="adress"` и `class="t-input js-tilda-rule"`.

Подскажите как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См. → [CSS селекторы](https://webref.ru/css#selectors)

`<input name="adress" class="t-input js-tilda-rule">`

```
$(function() {
  let $input = $('[name="adress"].t-input.js-tilda-rule');

  if ($input.length) {
    $input.val( localStorage.getItem("example-name-adress") || "" );

    $input.on('input', function() {
      localStorage.setItem("example-name-adress", $(this).val() );
    });
  }
});
```

↑ или без jQ ↓

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let input = document.querySelector('[name="adress"].t-input.js-tilda-rule');

  if (input) {
    input.value = localStorage.getItem("example-name-adress") || "";

    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
      localStorage.setItem("example-name-adress", this.value);
    });
  }
});
```